# Having issues with file_get_contents and then perform a task on each line?

Tags: php, foreach, file-get-contents

I have a file that will end up having maybe 2-5 different domains in it.

I would like to use file_get_contents to parse out each line and then

```
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$file = "monitor-available.txt";
$lines = file('testingdomains.txt');

for ($x=0; $x<=15; $x++) 

foreach($lines as $line){

usleep(125000); // sleep 1/8 of a second 

$time = date("h:i:s");
$result = gethostbyname($line);
$query = $time . " - " .$result. "\r";

file_put_contents($file, $query, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}
```

This works when I have one domain in the text file the result will look like:

> $time - (IP address from gethostbyname)

However if I add in multiple domain names into the text file it returns:

> $time - domain1 $time - domain2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for ($x=0; $x<=15; $x++) ` --- what's this for?

Comment: From what very little PHP I know, I believe that's telling it to loop 15 (16 counting 0?) times. Now that I look at the code, nothing since it doesn't have brackets to the next section. Added them and still the same end result.

Comment: What I would like to see with this test script is when a domain shifts from pendingDelete to available if the IP address changes and on average at what time it does. So I will run this for about 15 minutes and check 4 times a minute for each domain in the file gethostbyname($line) ... forgive the messiness.. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$file = "monitor-available.txt";
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('testingdomains.txt'));
$query = "";
foreach($lines as $line){
    usleep(125000); // sleep 1/8 of a second 
    $time = date("h:i:s");
    $result = gethostbyname($line);
    $query .= $time . " - " .$result. "\n";
}
file_put_contents($file, $query, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

This is better for IO cause only one file write. But if you need the data output to file immediately then this is not an option